# Setup macbook pro for ruby on rails development

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I just got my first Macbook :).
And now I want to configure it for Ruby on rails development.
I want to setup following things:

- Textmate
- Ruby using RVM
- Rails
- Mysql
- Postgresql
- Apache

Also I am new to Xcode.

Comment: sure I can transfer it for you

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I want to install things listed above. I googled about, but found different tools/method being used for installation eg. Macports/homebrew. I need some instructions or pointer to a good tutorial that will help me to install things above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this? [setting up rails on snow leopard](http://spyrestudios.com/setting-up-a-rails-development-system-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/) or this? [Mac Setup](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/mac-setup/) or this? [Installing Rails on Lion](http://www.frederico-araujo.com/2011/07/30/installing-rails-on-os-x-lion-with-homebrew-rvm-and-mysql/)

This is a really common combo these days it wasn't hand to find a few walk-through descriptions.

Also, let me recommend osx-gcc-installer is you just want a compiler and don't plan on using XCode. I find XCode to be useless unless you're planning on writing Mac or iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

See [Installing Ruby, Rails, and MySQL on OS X Lion | Think Vitamin](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/ruby-on-rails/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion/). Basically you'll have to dowload and install Xcode from the App Store, install Ruby and MySQL with Homebrew, and Rails with RubyGems.